# insert html code to a page via php script in other page

Tags: php, html, forms, indexing

i'm a little bit new for php so maybe this question is stupid.

say i have a form:

```
<form id="createNewGallery" name="newgallery" method="GET" action="code.php"><p><strong>please choose the number of pictures you want to upload:
  </strong>
  <select name="numOfPictures" id="numOfPictures">

      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>6</option>
      <option>7</option>
      <option>8</option>
      <option>9</option>
      <option>10</option>
  </select></p>
  <input name="submitNumOfPictures" type="submit" />
</form>
```

by submiting this form i want to add afterwards another form, i know i can do it in this particular page but i just want my code not to be messy, so i want to do it in another page, say code.php

and this is the code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['numOfPictures'])){

    $times = $_GET['numOfPictures'];
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $times; $i++){
        echo '<br />select picture number '.$i.': <br />';
        echo '<input name="file'.$i.'" type="file" />';

    }
    echo '</br><input name="submitFiles" type="submit" />';

}
```

the result im getting is an output in a new page, code.php, but i want it to create a form just afterwards the for i had on my index php.

i get the required result if i do mt php coding in the index page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways of managing this, depending on your ultimate goal.

You can just use separate files, and when user submits the form, it goes to the next page, ie.
firstform.php -> SUBMIT goes to -> secondform.php, and so on.
This way if you check their inputs and not what you like, you can send them back to the previous page/form with some error message to correct their choices.

You can Use either GET as you are now, or POST

You can use one page/file (say forms.php) and use PHP to determine what stage the user is at.
Example - say you have user enter number of pictures they want, then ask for their details (may not be what you need but you get the flow idea)

```
//FORM 1 - get number of pictures
if ($_GET['whichform'] == '')
  {
    echo '<form id="createNewGallery" name="newgallery" method="GET"
           action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'"">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="whichform" value="form1" />';
    echo '<input name="submitNumOfPictures" type="submit" />';
  }

//FORM 2 - number of pictures submitted so ask for their details
elseif ($_GET['whichform'] == 'form1')
  {
    echo '<form id="GetUserDetails" name="userdetails" method="GET"
           action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'"">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="whichform" value="form2" />';
    echo '<input name="userdetails" type="submit" />';
  }
```

This will let you start with FORM1, once submitted the GET info will return true for if is FORM1, and so it will show FORM 2, and so on for FORM 3, 4, 5, etc
It's a crude way in some ways, and needs tweaking (ie testing if the submitted data is as you expect etc) but it gives you the idea on how to manage multiple forms on one page.

Answer (score 0):

As Filippo Toso said, you may include the HTML file in your code.php.

Perhaps, if you don't want to have two files, you may make only one file and set the form to act like that:

```
<form id="createNewGallery" name="newgallery" method="GET" action="./"><p><strong>please choose the number of pictures you want to upload:
  </strong>
  <select name="numOfPictures" id="numOfPictures">
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>6</option>
      <option>7</option>
      <option>8</option>
      <option>9</option>
      <option>10</option>
  </select></p>
  <input name="submitNumOfPictures" type="submit" />
</form>
<?php

if (isset($_GET['numOfPictures'])){

    $times = $_GET['numOfPictures'];
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $times; $i++){
        echo '<br />select picture number '.$i.': <br />';
        echo '<input name="file'.$i.'" type="file" />';

    }
    echo '</br><input name="submitFiles" type="submit" />';

}
?>
```

(note the "action" of the form)

This is, maybe, pointless, compared to the previous solution but if you don't want to have two files you may do that in once, so that once you submit you will get the results right after your form without needing any other page!

edit: forgot to mention that I suppose your file is named "index.php". If not, just replace the "./" with the correct address!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<form id="createNewGallery" name="newgallery" method="post" action="code.php">
<p><strong>
please choose the number of pictures you want to upload:
  </strong>
  <select name="numOfPictures" id="numOfPictures">

      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option  value="4">4</option>
      <option  value="5">5</option>
      <option  value="6">6</option>
      <option  value="7">7</option>
      <option  value="8">8</option>
      <option  value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
  </select></p>
  <input name="submitNumOfPictures" type="submit" />
</form>
```

code.php

```
<?php
$times = $_POST['numOfPictures'];

echo $times;

?>
```