# Add Css class to a specific div in PHP Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Below php code removes the sidebar From the page when that is on 2nd depth but on same when this function removes the sidebar on same page i want to change the class of the below div to "Fullwidth" as my page has side bar the same css is applicable on page where sidebar is not present and the page is of half width.

```
    function so_32165017_conditionally_remove_sidebar(){
        if( is_product_category()){
            $t_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
            if( so_32165017_get_product_cat_depth( $t_id ) < 2 ){
                remove_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10 );
                // could be theme specific ex: Storefront
                remove_action( 'storefront_sidebar', 'storefront_get_sidebar', 10 );




            }
        }
    }
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'so_32165017_conditionally_remove_sidebar' );
```

HTML:

From:

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
```

To:

```
<div id="primary" class="fullwidth">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use js/jquery  for this, which is applied **after** the page loads.

```
$("#primary").removeClass("content-area");

$("#primary").addClass("fullwidth");
```

Comment: the above is a php code are you sure this Jquery is gonna work ??

Comment: then u can call js after page load.... like below code  $(document).ready(function() {
 
$("#primary").removeClass("content-area");

$("#primary").addClass("fullwidth");

});

Comment: should i have to add this in a function.php and a have a question i want to remove this only when the above php removes the sidebar the css should be triggered

Comment: Nope, you can simply link the script in your HTML `<head>` like `<script src="your/path/script.js"></script>`.

Comment: if u want mind can you add re edit my question code with your answer am confused where to add this

Comment: this is a wordpress theme if a add so this will remove by any chance this will remove all the class where ever this script is pointed up

Comment: No,  you can use this code only in view. in case of word press you can write it in template file ..

Comment: So it sounds like you want to insert HTML content with PHP.  I'm not a WordPress user, so I'd have to do some research, but [this post about inserting HTML via PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448411/insert-html-code-to-a-page-via-php-script-in-other-page) may help.

Comment: Defiantly i can give solution like that, but that is not a good way to do this work see my next answer it will work for you

Comment: @UltraSonja , there will be no insert just when the php is triggered to remove the sidebar say in if condition at that point of time just the class should shuffle that's it. and the theme is storefront in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

For your case just replace your code with this one...

```
function so_32165017_conditionally_remove_sidebar(){
        if( is_product_category()){
            $t_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
            if( so_32165017_get_product_cat_depth( $t_id ) < 2 ){
                remove_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10 );
                // could be theme specific ex: Storefront
                remove_action( 'storefront_sidebar', 'storefront_get_sidebar', 10 );


                echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $("#primary").removeClass("content-area"); 
                        $("#primary").addClass("fullwidth"); 
                    });
               </script>';

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: dint work showing the same ma be the function of php is loading before the html code is loaded am not sure

Comment: i just added a alert to check whether is it working on Dom ready the alert don't show up

Answer (score 0):

you need to do this.

```
 $('#testID2').addClass('fullwidth').removeClass('content-area');
```

Comment: but where the entire site goes down if i add this in if condition